# Problems with runUrl in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to have my first shiny app be available from my website using the runUrl() function in shiny.

I have uploaded the zip file to my server and used the following code

```
library(shiny)
runUrl("http://www.sampassmore.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/test.zip")
```

But I continually get the error:

```
Downloading http://www.sampassmore.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/test.zip
Error in setwd(appDir) : cannot change working directory
```

I am rather stumped as how to proceed, since I don't personally use setwd() in the code. There must be some code within the shiny process that does, but I do not know where or how to fix it.

Sam

Comment: Probably related to this issue https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/220

Comment: @jdharrison You are right. It is a known bug, and a fix is on its way: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/pull/488 Thanks!